Laravel app getting "[1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'172.19.0.4'" error when connecting to MySQL Docker container
I'm facing an issue connecting my Laravel application to a MySQL Docker container. When I run php artisan migrate, I'm getting the following error:
 SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'172.19.0.4' (using password: YES) (Connection: mysql, SQL: select table_name as `name`, (data_length + index_length) as `size`, table_comment as `comment`, engine as `engine`, table_collation as `collation` from information_schema.tables where table_schema = 'project' and table_type in ('BASE TABLE', 'SYSTEM VERSIONED') order by table_name)

I can access the MySQL database using a MySQL client, but the Laravel application fails to connect.
Here's my .env file:
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=mysql_db
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=adrian_project
DB_USERNAME=user
DB_PASSWORD="password"

And my Docker Compose file:
networks:
    laravel_environment:
        driver: bridge

services:
    #App server
    php:
        build:
            dockerfile: ./php/Dockerfile
        ports:
            - "80:80"
            - "5173:5173"
        volumes:
            - ./tap-and-stack:/var/www/html
        links:
            - mysql_db
        networks:
            - laravel_environment
   
   #MYSQL Service
   mysql_db:
       image: mysql:5.7
       platform: 'linux/x86_64'
       container_name: mysql_db
       #volumes:
       #     - /opt/mysql_db:/var/lib/mysql#~
       ports:
           - 3306:3306
       environment:
           MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: "root"
           MYSQL_USER: user
           MYSQL_PASSWORD: "password"
           MYSQL_DATABASE: adrian_project
           MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD: 1
       networks:
           - laravel_environment
   phpmyadmin:
       image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
       ports:
           - 8001:80
       environment:
           - PMA_ARBITRARY=1
           - PMA_HOST=mysql_db
           - PMS_PORT=3306
       depends_on:
           - mysql_db
       networks:
           - laravel_environment

I've tried checking the database credentials, network connectivity, and MySQL user permissions, but I couldn't find the issue. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Run these commands and try again php artisan config:clear and php artisan cache:clear.

Dangggg, I just successfully run the migration. Weird, I tried that two command before but it didn't work. What I did is build the docker images and run those two command and it finally worked. Thanks!

I finally fixed this by re-building the images and run php artisan config:clear and php artisan cache:clear.
